# android : is constraint layout support RTL

Tags: android, right-to-left

what is the best practice to support RTL in constraint layout in android Studio,
or should I create A separated layouts one for English and the other for Arabic?

English Version

[image: English version]

The Expected layout with Arabic language
[image: The Expected layout with Arabic language]

The output layout when I change the Device Language from English to Arabic 
[image: The output layout when Change the Language from English to Arabic]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/CourseName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1" />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/enroll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display2" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: "is constraint layout support RTL" -- yes, if you use `...Start` and `...End` rules, rather than `...Left` and `...Right` rules.

Comment: What is the problem? your pics seems normal to me! in RTL the layout is reversed as like mirror. So i you will target Arabic deceives only you need to design your layout while the designer is on rtl view

Comment: actually, rtl is used to support different languages for ex English , Arabic. So on **LTR** view your text should be English not Arabic as you did.

Comment: i need the output layout to be the expected layout . The first image is the expected layout but the Second is what i get .

Comment: @MartinMarconcini: `ConstraintLayout` has `layout_constraintStart_toEndOf`, `layout_constraintStart_toStartOf`, `layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf`, and `layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf` attributes, consistent with my comment.

Comment: I don't know what does the ConstraintLayout do with RTL-LTR (I always wondered why things were not start/end vs. left/right) but in your particular case, I suppose you'd be better served by a small RelativeLayout.

Comment: @CommonsWare you're right, it was added a while ago, when I first used CL it didn't have them.

Comment: @ CommonsWare Will constraint start and end works in api 16?Why not add both left/right and start/end to support old and new versions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As Already pointed out by CommonsWare, you should *rarely/never* use Left/Right if you plan on supporting RTL languages, especially if you target API 16+.

Replace your `app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"` with `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"` and so forth.

End for Right, Start for Left.

Comment: Hey, How to make it work with guideline? it doesn't transpose to the other side of the screen when I change language which breaks layout

Comment: @zarcel I don't know. I haven't used guidelines in my layouts. Sorry!

Comment: @zarcel I had to use Guidelines and RTL/LTR support and what I did was store the guidelines positions in a `values/dimens.xml` and then overrode them in `values-ldrtl/dimens.xml` So, for LTR, say you have a guideline at 25% from the left and the other at 75%, you’d define: `<item type="fraction" name=“guideline_one”>0.25</item>` and `<item type="fraction" name=“guideline_two">0.75</item>`. In the `values-ldrtl` folder, you’d duplicate those and put the opposite value: `guideline_one` becomes 100-25=75 -> `0.75` and `guideline_two` becomes 100-75 = 25 so `0.25`.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, they don't do it right ( or, "End" ;-) ).

In many constraints, like constraint to parent, Android Studio creates constraints using "Left"/"Right" where it ought to use "Start"/"End" respectively. It causes a problem in RTL languages (Every single language that its alphabet is Middle-Eastern).

Worse: I even haven't seen any open bug about that, yet.

My solution: close Android Studio *(so it doesn't jump and try to fix things while I am editing)*, then, with Atom and RegExp (or a `sed` command), I carefully replace "`layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf`" to "`layout_constraintStart_toStartOf`" and "`layout_constraintRight_toRightOf`" to "`layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf`".

Sorry, haven't found anything less silly :-(

**Note**
With chaining it is even worse. RTL layout doesn't even chain well, nor does it maintain layout.

My conclusion at that case was to get back to the old Layouts till Google gives a mature support for the RTL languages... *after all, RTL has been here long before LTR ;-)*

### Update: A solution is near

I opened a bug to Google. They say it will be "Fixed in 2.4".

**Update:**

> [Marked as Fixed](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37324626#comment3)
>   Fixed in 2.4

on Apr 25, 2017

Comment: there are other expressions "layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf" and ""layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf" that play role in RTL include these as well in your sed command :)

Comment: Don't let Google developers catch you saying that! Mostly not those who put that warning in AndroidStudio inspections "...hard coded ...something" ;-)
Yeah, you can write a new layout for RTL... But... why maintaining 2 layout files when salvation is coming soon?

Comment: @Meymann Would you please give the link to this issue? (I mean _They say it will be "Fixed in 2.4"._ )

Comment: Note: You can find/replace in android studio (just close the preview). Chains: you can properly chain in RTL, the solution (so far) (1.0.3 beta 3) consists of putting the chain definition in **both** the `head` of the chain and the right-most item (horizontal) or bottom-most (vertical). So essentially you’re duplicating the chain style in both elements. The “offending” one is (at this time) ignored by ConstraintLayout (no side effects I could observe) and when in RTL, the chain is maintained.

Comment: @Mr.Hyde - The correspondence was here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37324626 but I chickened out. Did not have time to wait for them so I still use the old layout system... steady as she goes

Comment: @Meymann Good info, I reported CL + RTL issues here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70181930 and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70172298 and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70243928 all fixed in the next beta 4 (or so it says, I can’t use Beta in my current pro, so I still have to _workaround_ these things).

Answer (score 1):

[image]Design mode doesn't yet support RTL guidelines.

Simple Solution - 
Clean you project so that you don't have generated file.
Replace all "Left" with "Start"
all "Right" with "End" in you xml files.
Note - case sensitive

Thats it!!

Comment: That would be great in 2.4 (I hope). But for now, even spacing etc will do a mess of your layout on RTL... You won't be able to preview it well. It was so dreadful that it made me chicken out and quit constraint views for the old layout elements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes constraint layout supports RTL, but for using the RTL "start and end" constraints should be used instead of "left and right" constraints.

Example : 
                      Use
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                   instead of
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"

```
                  AND

                  Use
```

app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                   instead of
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"