# RecyclerView doesn't show items until scrolling in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-databinding, android-viewbinding

I have a `RecyclerView` that shows a list with `livedata`.

`RecyclerView` adapter is prepared with `viewBinding`.

My problem is that the `RecyclerView` does not show the items, but when I scroll the `RecyclerView`, the items are shown.

I've tried several solutions without success.

**Note:** `liveData` gets data from server with retrofit

**Fragment:**

```
    class DistanceListFragment : BaseFragment() {
        private var _binding: FragmentDistanceListBinding? = null
        private val binding get() = _binding!!
        private val distanceListViewModel : DistanceListViewModel by viewModel()
        private val distanceListAdapter = DistanceListAdapter()
    
        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
            _binding = FragmentDistanceListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
            val view = binding.root
            return view
        }
    
        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
            binding.recyclerViewDistanceList.layoutManager =
                LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
            binding.recyclerViewDistanceList.adapter = distanceListAdapter
            prepareDistanceListViewModel()
        }
    
        private fun prepareDistanceListViewModel(){
            distanceListViewModel.distanceListLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
                distanceListAdapter.distanceList = it as ArrayList<Distance>
            }
        }
    
        override fun onDestroyView() {
            super.onDestroyView()
            _binding = null
        }
    }
```

**Adapter :**

```
    class DistanceListAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<DistanceListAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
        var distanceList = ArrayList<Distance>()
            set(value) {
                field = value
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
    
        inner class ViewHolder(private val binding: ItemDistanceListBinding) :
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    
            fun bindDistance(distance: Distance) {
                Timber.i(distance.beginning)
                binding.textViewDistanceListBeginning.text = distance.beginning
                binding.textViewDistanceListDestination.text = distance.destination
                binding.textViewDistanceListDistance.text = "${distance.distance} کیلومتر"
            }
        }
    
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    
            return ViewHolder(
                ItemDistanceListBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
            )
        }
    
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) =
            holder.bindDistance(distanceList[position])
    
        override fun getItemCount(): Int = distanceList.size
    }
```

**Fragment Xml :**

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView_distanceList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            />
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Adapter Xml :**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_item_distance_list"
    >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_distanceList_topParent"
        style="@style/Guideline.All.TopParent"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.02"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_distanceList_bottomParent"
        style="@style/Guideline.All.BottomParent"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_distanceList_leftParent"
        style="@style/Guideline.All.LeftParent"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.98"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_distanceList_rightParent"
        style="@style/Guideline.All.RightParent"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.02"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_distanceList_destinationItemsRightSide"
        style="@style/Guideline.All.Vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.58" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_distanceList_beginningText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline_distanceList_leftParent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guideline_distanceList_rightParent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline_distanceList_topParent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:text="مبدا" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_distanceList_beginning"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline_distanceList_leftParent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_distanceList_beginningText"
        tools:text="بیرجند" />

    <TextView
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/textView_distanceList_destinationText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline_distanceList_destinationItemsRightSide"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline_distanceList_topParent"
        android:text="مقصد" />

    <TextView
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/textView_distanceList_destination"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline_distanceList_destinationItemsRightSide"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_distanceList_destinationText"
        tools:text="ایرانشهر" />

    <TextView
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/textView_distanceList_distance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline_distanceList_rightParent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_distanceList_destination"
        android:text="795 کیلومتر"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have attached an image showing what I mean:
[image]

Comment: Can you add code of ```ItemDistanceListBinding``` xml file ?

Comment: @jayesh gurudayalani added

Comment: Looks like the Items overflow the edge

Comment: Do they all suddenly pop into place when you start scrolling, or is it only new items that scroll onto the screen that look ok? Like *Fah* says, the items look like they're in the wrong place - but they seem like they're aligned to the opposite side of your guideline, with the end of the text aligned instead of the start. I don't know exactly what the problem is, but I bet it's related to RTL text - you're using `left` and `right` instead of `start` and `end` for your guidelines too. I'm not sure exactly what's going wrong, but I'd start looking there!

Comment: Someone here (https://stackoverflow.com/q/62774267/13598222) had a similar issue (no answer though), and a comment on this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42306144/13598222) suggests storing your `Guideline` positions as `dimen` resources that can be reversed for RLT locales (so instead of hardcoding *left* as *0.02*, you'd call it *start* and point it at a resource that's *0.02* for LTR locales and *0.98* for RTL ones). That's an old post though

Comment: @cactustictacs Thanks for your help I find the solution by set layoutDirection to Rtl in themes.xml

Answer (score 0):

You should be creating a variable in the recyclerview to pass the list of data. at the time of setting the adapter, you need to send the list value in it. Thus making sure that it has data when the recycler view is set. I will list an example below:

```
holder.recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 4)
    holder.recyclerView.adapter =
        AllAddonsInnerAdapterRV(
            dataList[position],
            optionsInterface,
            extrasItemClick
        )
```

here I am setting a recyclerview and at the time of initializing the adapter I am also passing the list of data to it. Let me know if you need further explanation.